# What happens if a browser doesn't support gzip?

Tags: .htaccess, cross-browser, gzip

I'm using `mod_deflate` to enable gzip on a site via the `.htaccess` file.

What happens if a browser that doesn't support gzip visits the site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then the server doesn't send gzip. That's the whole point of the "Accept-Encoding:" heading from the browser, which indicates this by not having "gzip" in that header.

Comment: thanks @Mark Adler, so in that instance would the server return a non gzipped version of the files ?