# header `Vary` - need better explanation/tutorial

Tags: .htaccess, header

I've spent time in reading about header `Vary` and i think, it is not well-documented and explained completely in internet. I will list in paragraphs what I've understood, and please correct me if I am wrong.

1) Does `Vary` instructs server, what to do? or server doesnt matter that, and it just is a signal understandable for browsers?

2) If i've enabled compression and caching  on my site, then does my site always return only compressed version of page?

3) If compression-disabled browser visits my site (and i have compression enabled), then what happens? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264297/what-happens-if-a-browser-doesnt-support-gzip), but cant understand well. What happens a)If I"ve set `Vary: Accept-encoding`; b) If I havent;

4) in same situation, if my site saves cached copied of pages and compression-disabled browser visits my site, What happens a)If I've set `Vary: Accept-encoding`; b) If I havent;

5) when I have enabled compression on my website and I've set header **Vary**, does it tell to proxies, that they should keep two versions of my page: Compressed (for browsers,which supporting compression) and Uncompressed(for browsers, which doesnt support compression)? How proxies get both versions of pages, if my site generates only compressed version?

6) What do proxies do if i have compression-enabled on my site, but havent set `Vary` header. Does proxies keep only 1 version(uncompressed) of my page, and serving that page to clients?

7) I have seen, that `Accept-Encoding, Cookie` caused caching not to work. After removing the word `Cookie`, it starts caching (see report [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wf-makes-problems-in-htaccess-caching?replies=1#post-8786779)). why?

8) I had other question, however, forgot at this moment..