# Implementing a fallback for gzip files in browser

Tags: javascript, html, http, gzip

I am hosting gzip files on my server and sending them to the frontend.
I want to implement a fallback so that if the browser does not accept gzip files / gzip files are not sent with the proper http headers (content-encoding: gzip), then I will just serve a regular inflated js file.

The browser throws the following console error when a gzip file is sent without headers:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

How can I catch this error in the browser?

Comment: How exactly are you enabling gzip compression? Because you shouldn't have to implement a fallback mechanism in the first place. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264297/what-happens-if-a-browser-doesnt-support-gzip

Comment: You shouldn't. You should configure your server properly to only serve gzip if the browser accepts gzip

Comment: The web server should gzip compress the files on the fly if the browser accepts that compression algorithm

Comment: I am hosting files on aws, and currently in my project it is a manual process to set headers on files. I want to avoid errors caused by someone forgetting to do this....

Comment: Don't do this; just enable compression in your aws settings. You're trying to solve a problem you created yourself unnecessarily

Comment: @ChrisG Is it possible to auto set headers on certain files in aws?
The problem is that for prod builds, we manually copy an existing dir, and rename it. so it would have to be a global setting across our entire bucket on aws....

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, are you trying to turn on compression for *all* files, or just for *specific* files? I've also never used aws.

Comment: Update: I have essentially resolved this by adding flags to my aws command located in my yaml file on circleci, I used the ```--metadata-directive COPY --content-encoding gzip``` flag to add metadata headers to the files.
This adds headers as the files get pushed to aws.